# ubuntu-gnome 16.04 32 bit invalid encoding file automatically generated in home directory

Tags: 16.04, ubuntu-gnome

[image]

0@@X@8@!@@@@@��@@@@�� (invalid encoding)

automatic generate empty file in my home directory.If i delete this file then automatic regenerate again.

thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem, although the file only appears occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that this file gets generated when you open/run a few particular programs. This is because of the mismatch in type of OS and the software being opened/run.
Type in the command

```
uname -m
```

If you get i686, you have a 32-bit version of Linux. 
If you get x86_64, you have a 64-bit version of Linux.
So now install the same version of the software that you want to use. Or also check the dependencies that the software uses.
For instance you have a 32bit OS. And you should use PHPStorm 32 bit, and PHPStorm needs jvm, then you need to install java 32 bit.

Comment: this is logically not possible to install 64bit software in 32 bit system.